# next js / separated express api to production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, hosting

I have developed full stack next js ( as a frontend ) and separated express server as a backend, I run in problem when I wanted to deploy it. I'm wondering what'll be the best way to do it without losing next js performances as a framework. I have read some articles saying that the application is good to be deployed separated ( let's say frontend on vercel and backend on heroku ). I developed this project for customer who already had really old website and he's paying for C-panel hosting. I'm not sure what to do, Can i maybe deploy somehow the full project on that c-panel or something else.This is really important to me, and i can't find a specific answer. Thank you in advance.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Both your frontend and backend require a node environment. C-panel hosting usually means PHP though. Can you clarify whether the client's hosting has node support at all?

Comment: @ChrisG They say that there is support for Node js

Comment: So can you deploy more than one node app?

Comment: @ChrisG As I know you can have up to 2 apps. 
I just read one article that says "No Automatic Static Optimization", should that be a problem?

Comment: No idea, maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987976/why-does-a-next-js-custom-server-disable-automatic-static-optimization

Comment: @ChrisG Useful article, thank you. So as I understood, I should run next js app from my express api using custom server, and then deploy to C-panel? Are there more steps that I missed or understood it completely wrong?

Comment: You need to deploy the nextjs app and the express app as if they were two completely separate apps (because they are). You say the hosting supports up to 2 node apps, so that should work fine. The only thing you need to make sure is that the API calls from your deployed nextjs app are made to your deployed express server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245245/discussion-between-andrej-velkov-and-chris-g).